# asmselect jquery plugin - selecting option multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, asmselect

How to select with ASMSelect the same option multiple times?
For example, "Amsterdam" 5 times.

http://www.ryancramer.com/projects/asmselect/examples/example1.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a select control is the right control for your requirements. I think you will need to create a custom control that keeps track of selections and increments a count.